# error 'TheNavBar' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm pretty new to Nuxt as I'm a server side guy, but I'm trying to make a component for my Navbar and its claiming I'm not using it anywhere. I am see I'm clearly using it in my layout.

Is this just ESLint complaining for no reason or is it a nuxt related issue like not picking up the component usage correctly?

I've also tried renaming the component to Navbar like the components file name, no luck results in the same issue.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TheNavBar />
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TheNavBar from '@/components/Navbar';
export default {};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Navbar.vue

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            <img
              src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png"
              width="112"
              height="28"
            />
          </a>

          <a
            role="button"
            class="navbar-burger burger"
            aria-label="menu"
            aria-expanded="false"
            data-target="navbarBasicExample"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

The error when running `npm run dev` was this

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                     friendly-errors 22:59:49


 ERROR  in ./layouts/inside.vue                                                                                             friendly-errors 22:59:49

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                               friendly-errors 22:59:49

/home/ash/code/cascade-pwa/cascade-pwa/layouts/inside.vue
  9:8  error  'TheNavBar' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

                                                                                                                            friendly-errors 22:59:49
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js 13:0-46 16:13-22
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
                                                                                                                            friendly-errors 22:59:49
```

Answer (score 2):

So you got 2 mistakes in your code.

1.
vue components in the template are kebap-cased that means your `<TheNavBar />`

should be `<the-nav-bar />`

2. You imported the component but did not use it inside your script

`export default {};`

changed to

```
<script>
import TheNavBar from '@/components/Navbar';
export default {
  components: { TheNavBar }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand how it knows where TheNavBar is located? Getting `'Navbar' is not defined` with your code.

Comment: @Ketchum you have to still import it and then pass the imported component into the components property like in my code. Keep your import.